# I get an error of a parameter that cannot be nil obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, function, null

this function is the copy of another identical but with different keys. on the other hand it works I can't understand why the app crashes here ..

```
    #pragma mark - ChangePin
- (void) doChangePin: (NSString *) pinUser card: (NSString *) pinCard viewController: (UIViewController *) viewController success:(successSDKType)success failure:(failureSDKType)failure{

    self.mcPersonalEnrollmentRequest.mcCardPan = pinCard;

    PRLog(@"Pin Inserito: %@", pinUser);

    SecurityCryptogram *securityCryptogram = [CryptogramManager getSecurityCriptogramWithPan:pinCard pin:pinUser];

    self.mcPersonalEnrollmentRequest.securityCryptogram = securityCryptogram;
    self.mcPersonalEnrollmentRequest.mcIdPublicKey = [[ServiceDataManager getInstance] getIdPublicKey];

    NSDictionary* dtoReq = [self.mcPersonalEnrollmentRequest getDictionary];

    [self.netManager doRequestWithCommand:CMD_STATUS_CHECK dtoReq:dtoReq successCompletion:^(NetworkResponse *successData) {

        NSDictionary *resources = (NSDictionary *)[successData res];

        McCardEnrolled *mcCardEnrolled = [[McCardEnrolled alloc] initWithResDict:resources];
        [[ServiceDataManager getInstance] storeMcCard:mcCardEnrolled];

        McCard *mcCard = [mcCardEnrolled getCard];

        //We have to go on main thread to pop the controller
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            self.mcCardEnrollmentSuccessCallback(mcCard);
            self.cardEnrollmentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
            [self.cardEnrollmentViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            self.cardEnrollmentViewController = nil;
            self.mcCardEnrollmentSuccessCallback = nil;
            self.mcCardEnrollmentFailureCallback = nil;
            self.mcCardEnrollmentRequest = nil;

        }];


    } failureCompletion:^(Result *failureResult) {

        //Same of success case. We have to go on main thread to pop the controller
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            self.mcCardEnrollmentFailureCallback(failureResult);
            self.cardEnrollmentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
            [self.cardEnrollmentViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            self.cardEnrollmentViewController = nil;
            self.mcCardEnrollmentSuccessCallback = nil;
            self.mcCardEnrollmentFailureCallback = nil;
            self.mcCardEnrollmentRequest = nil;
        }];

    }];
```

the error is :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: req)'

the objects or variables that change are as follows:
mcPersonalEnrollmentRequest
CMD_STATUS_CHECK
that I recreated for this function here.

```
- (void) doRequestWithCommand:(NSString*)cmd dtoReq:(NSDictionary*)dtoReq successCompletion:(successCompletionType)success failureCompletion:(failureCompletionType)failure{

PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - Prepare request with dtoReq: %@",cmd,[dtoReq description]);

NetworkRequest *request = [self prepareRequestForCommand:cmd dtoReq:dtoReq];
PRLog(@"NET-REQ> CMD:%@ - [DEBUG] Request created", cmd);

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - Received response. Error: %@", cmd, [error description]);

    if (!error) {
        // Success
        NSString *errMsg;
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {

            NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [PRUtility dictionaryFromJsonData:data];
            if(jsonResponse){
                PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - JSON RESPONSE != nil", cmd);

                NSDictionary* svcResDict = (NSDictionary*)[jsonResponse objectForKey:DTO_RESPONSE_TAG_SVC];
                if(svcResDict && svcResDict != (NSDictionary *)[NSNull null]){

                    PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - Trying parsing response.",cmd);
                    NetworkResponse* networkResponse = [[NetworkResponse alloc] initWithCmd:cmd andNetworkData:svcResDict];

                    if (networkResponse) {
                        //Happy flow
                        PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - Response created correctly.",cmd);

                        Result* resultForBadStatusCode = [self errorFromStatusCode:networkResponse.dtoStatus];

                        !resultForBadStatusCode ? success(networkResponse) : failure(resultForBadStatusCode);
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                        errMsg = @"Error while accessing to networkResponse";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    errMsg = @"SVC field not found";
                }
            }
            else{
                errMsg = @"Cannot parses response into json";
            }
        }  else {
            errMsg = @"Recevied an error [response is not a NSHTTPURLResponse]";
        }

        Result *errorResponse = [[Result alloc] initGenericErrorWithMalformedNetworkResponse:errMsg];

        PRLog(@"NET-MAN: CMD:%@ - ERR: %@", cmd, errMsg);
        failure(errorResponse);

    } else {
        // Fail

        Result *errorNetwork = [self errorNetworkFromCode:error.code];

        PRLog(@"NET-MAN: CMD:%@ - ERR: %@", cmd, error.description);
        failure(errorNetwork);
    }

}];

PRLog(@"NET-MAN: CMD:%@ - Doing request...", request.cmd);
[task resume];
```

}

```
- (void) doRequestWithCommand:(NSString*)cmd dtoReq:(NSDictionary*)dtoReq successCompletion:(successCompletionType)success failureCompletion:(failureCompletionType)failure{

    PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - Prepare request with dtoReq: %@",cmd,[dtoReq description]);

    NetworkRequest *request = [self prepareRequestForCommand:cmd dtoReq:dtoReq];
    PRLog(@"NET-REQ> CMD:%@ - [DEBUG] Request created", cmd);

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - Received response. Error: %@", cmd, [error description]);

        if (!error) {
            // Success
            NSString *errMsg;
            if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {

                NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [PRUtility dictionaryFromJsonData:data];
                if(jsonResponse){
                    PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - JSON RESPONSE != nil", cmd);

                    NSDictionary* svcResDict = (NSDictionary*)[jsonResponse objectForKey:DTO_RESPONSE_TAG_SVC];
                    if(svcResDict && svcResDict != (NSDictionary *)[NSNull null]){

                        PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - Trying parsing response.",cmd);
                        NetworkResponse* networkResponse = [[NetworkResponse alloc] initWithCmd:cmd andNetworkData:svcResDict];

                        if (networkResponse) {
                            //Happy flow
                            PRLog(@"NET-MAN> CMD:%@ - Response created correctly.",cmd);

                            Result* resultForBadStatusCode = [self errorFromStatusCode:networkResponse.dtoStatus];

                            !resultForBadStatusCode ? success(networkResponse) : failure(resultForBadStatusCode);
                            return;
                        }
                        else{
                            errMsg = @"Error while accessing to networkResponse";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        errMsg = @"SVC field not found";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    errMsg = @"Cannot parses response into json";
                }
            }  else {
                errMsg = @"Recevied an error [response is not a NSHTTPURLResponse]";
            }

            Result *errorResponse = [[Result alloc] initGenericErrorWithMalformedNetworkResponse:errMsg];

            PRLog(@"NET-MAN: CMD:%@ - ERR: %@", cmd, errMsg);
            failure(errorResponse);

        } else {
            // Fail

            Result *errorNetwork = [self errorNetworkFromCode:error.code];

            PRLog(@"NET-MAN: CMD:%@ - ERR: %@", cmd, error.description);
            failure(errorNetwork);
        }

    }];

    PRLog(@"NET-MAN: CMD:%@ - Doing request...", request.cmd);
    [task resume];

}

    - (NetworkRequest*) prepareRequestForCommand:(NSString*)cmd dtoReq:(NSDictionary*)dtoReq{
    NSMutableDictionary* dtoAppRequest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dtoAppRequest setObject:cmd
                      forKey:CMD_TAG];
    [dtoAppRequest setObject:dtoReq forKey:REQ_TAG];

    NetworkRequest *request = [[NetworkRequest alloc] initWithDtoAppRequest:dtoAppRequest
                                                             jSessionClient:self.userConfig.jSessionClient
                                                                     userId:self.userConfig.userId
                                                                 fiscalCode:self.userConfig.fiscalCode];

    [request completeRequestObject];

    return request;
}
```

Comment: I don't see mutable dictionary here, so crash should be in some other place.

Comment: @Asperi mm i update the code.. i insert method invocated in do ChangePin

Comment: @can we write on skype? it's a simple mistake, i'm sure it will fix it right away please

Comment: Hi Stefano welcome to SO. Presenting us with a wall of unrelated code doesn’t help us with solving the issue. Could you edit to include only the few lines that are causing you an issue. Please read the site guide on what makes a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line that generates nil, and nil cannot be inserted in NSMutableDictionary,

```
NSDictionary* dtoReq = [self.mcPersonalEnrollmentRequest getDictionary];
```

Just add validation for this parameter with some handling and all will be ok.